# Eclipse Plugin Dev: Unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

Based on this [simple tutorial](http://stacktrace.be/blog/2009/11/09/eclipse-plugin-development-show-custom-mylyn-notification-dialog/), I am trying to display pop-ups notifications, as part of the org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui dependency. So I have added this dependency to my plugin.xml as such:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Roll and Scroll Recorder
Bundle-SymbolicName: ATF_Recorder_Plugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.0.502
Bundle-Activator: com.jcraft.eclipse.jcterm.JCTermPlugin
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 com.jcraft.jsch;bundle-version="0.1.31",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.101",
 org.eclipse.jsch.core;bundle-version="1.1.300",
 com.jcraft.eclipse.jsch.core,
 org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui;bundle-version="3.6.1"
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-Vendor: OSEHRA
```

Additionally I clicked compute dependencies within my Feature project and now have this updated into my feature.xml file:

```
<requires>
  <import plugin="org.eclipse.ui"/>
  <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.runtime"/>
  <import plugin="com.jcraft.jsch" version="0.1.31" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
  <import plugin="org.eclipse.core.resources" version="3.7.101" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
  <import plugin="org.eclipse.jsch.core" version="1.1.300" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
  <import plugin="com.jcraft.eclipse.jsch.core"/>
  <import plugin="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui" version="3.6.1" match="greaterOrEqual"/>
</requires>
```

However when I installed my custom plugin, and go to show it's view, the dependency is never being resolved:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.provisional.commons.ui.AbstractNotificationPopup
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:626)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:601)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:562)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:486)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:459)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:400)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at com.jcraft.eclipse.jcterm.JCTermView.createPartControl(JCTermView.java:189)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.showView(Perspective.java:2245)
...
```

Comment: Are you using a target platform? What platform version are you building against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the lesson from this question is

`Don't ever use non-API classes, unless you don't care if your plug-in breaks in future versions`.

I guess you have to build your plug-in twice, if you absolutely need backward compatibility.

But, since

- you are targeting Indigo (3.7)
- the bug, in the context of which the provisional packages became API, is [Bug 360301](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=360301)
- this bug fix was included in Mylyn 3.7

you are probably best of requiring `org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui`, version 3.7 and later.

Since you are using Eclipse 3.6 for development, you will have to set up a target platform including a 3.7 installation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're running the plugin against the same version of mylyn that you built against? In newer versions of mylyn (3.8.0 for example) that class has been moved to package `org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui.dialog`.

Comment: I'm building it in  Indigo Service Release 2 and testing it on the very same build.

Comment: Also that package is not visible from the wizard, so I'm taking it that I am using the prior version of mylyn/eclipse..

Comment: Testing with `Run as`>`Eclipse Application` ?

Comment: On the "Run As" menu select "Run Configurations". Go to the plugins tab for your application and scroll down to the 'org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui' plugin. What version is that?

Comment: 3.6.1 (note, I had to deselect 'all workspace and enabled target plug-ins' and select 'plug-ins selected below only' to get this to show up)

Answer (score 0):

Issue: Even though the "same" Indigo SR 2 version of Eclipse is being used, they are not equal. Some of them have 3.6 version of `org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui` other have 3.8 (which is supposed to be in Juno only...).

Comment: This is because you have updated the Mylyn feature in one of them.

Comment: @tkotisis how did that update occur? Those instances of eclipse were freshly setup (unzipped) and immediately used to install just the custom plugin only.

Comment: Did you unzip the same zip file for both?