# Problems in Eclipse after ADT update

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I installed an update for ADT for solving problems described here -> [Eclipse Plugin Dev: Unable to resolve dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457031/eclipse-plugin-dev-unable-to-resolve-dependencies)

Now I am getting new errors like this:

```
Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.jdt.ui//icons/full/eview16/source.gif".
Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.jdt.ui//icons/full/eview16/javadoc.gif".
```

and here is the pic from my Package explorer:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Updating ADT plugin dependencies is not recommended unless you know what to do. Usually, we update/fix the dependencies of the ADT plugin via "Check for updates...", or "Install new software" in the Help context menu, depending on seriousness. Two things you can try: (A) Uninstalling ADT plugin, then reinstall ADT plugin (newer version). (B) Since the dependencies are from Eclipse, and not ADT plugin, the best chance to fix this is to reinstall Eclipse, and reinstall ADT plugin.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I updated ADT from "Сheck for updates", no additional steps were taken.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Eclipse? Or do a fresh installation of Eclipse and ADT plugin in a new location on your hard drive, with a new workspace location, etc.?

Comment: @tom_mai78101 Yes, that is what i did to finally solve a problem. Completely removed Eclipse, installed new version. Moving ADT location wasn't necesseary. Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1):

'Check for updates' can result in the error you have.

**To fix**: Help > Install New Software... > What is already installed? (link near bottom right) > Installation History (tab) > Select 2nd row > Revert